# How to describe dataframe category into section and content in r-markdown pdf?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, pdflatex

```
df

Id  Section       Comment
------------------------------------------------------------
1   Product A   this is the general comment for product A
2   Product A   this is the general comment for product A
3   Product A   this is the general comment for product A
4   Product B   this is the general comment for product B
5   Product B   this is the general comment for product B
8   Product C   this is the general comment for product C
9   Product C   this is the general comment for product C
10  Product C   this is the general comment for product C
```

the above one is my dataframe. i'm looking for output some thing like this

```
expected output:
------------------
Product A
this is the general comment for product A
this is the general comment for product A

Product B
this is the general comment for product B
this is the general comment for product B
```

if i'm looping through  every row i'm getting `section and comment section and comment` in this way

i tried to use based on index of section like the below code

mycode

```
section_df<-df%>%select("Section")%>% dplyr::mutate(r_number = row_number()) %>%
group_by(`Section`) %>%
dplyr::summarise(index = min(r_number))

section_df<-section_df[order(section_df$index),]
```

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  if(section_df$index[i] == i){
    
    cat(df$Section[i])
    cat(df$Comment[i])

  }else{
    cat(df$Comment[i])
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
section_df<-section_df[complete.cases(section_df), ]

for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  
  if(i %in% section_df$index){
    print(df$Section[i])
  }
  else{
    print(df$Comment[i])
  }

}
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. Give some context and explanation, why this code solves the particular problem.